# How to get correct date not by system date in php

Tags: php

How to get correct date not by system date in php

For ex: actual date is `24/4/2013`, but I changed my system date is `25/4/2013`.

**How can get correct date ie `24/4/2013`?**

Comment: there has to be some source which php uses..

Comment: Set correct system time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP can't inherently know that your system time is incorrect. As others have pointed out, you can query an authoritative source (similar to the [solution offered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6959114/get-time-from-timeserver)) instead.

EDIT: [shortcut to the time server query example](http://www.kloth.net/software/timesrv1.php)

Comment: Thanks for your link. But I have another issue with server time. Server time zone differs with my local time zone. SO i cannot use server time i guess..

Comment: That's a bit of an extreme response for a simple time zone issue. All that you need to do is figure out what timezone the connection is responding with, then convert that time to the timezone of interest.

Answer (score 2):

http://tf.nist.gov/tf-cgi/servers.cgi

,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

Answer (score 0):

Set the default time zone prior to use the `date()` function.

For instance:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
// or 
// date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Madrid')

echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Unfortunately, your answer is not what OP wants. TimeZone would not help, if system date was explicitly set to falsy one, or not properly configured, i.e. when system datetime was set with wrong year. Please note another answers. **P.S.:** And check out code highlight options with formatting abilities.