# Central Clock for Developers? Needed for a Network of Sites. 1 Time to Rule Them All

Tags: php, apache, networking, time, clock

I have a network of sites which comminicate to eachother all sorts of events and functionality.

Having a combined analytics system, I realized the need for a **central clock**, to put them all, perfectly, on the same schedule down to the millisecond.

Right now I'm using a typical timestamp format:

```
<?php date('Y-m-d H:i:s') ?>
```

**This is different for all servers, of course. I was hoping to achieve a way to get that very same 'Y-m-d H:i:s' from an online, central clock or service.**

Does such a thing exist? It should be as reliable as getting jquery from google.

---

Its with pain that I write this, I simply cannot stop myself from compulsively asking this knowing it will get a downvote! But it is a serious issue and good question!

Comment: "This is different for all servers, of course" then your servers are wrong. time is universal (ok its relative Einstein), perhaps you need to attend to how the servers get the time

Comment: "Time is an illusion. Lunchtime doubly so." -- Douglass Adams

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sync with NTP. NTP is a central clock, where various computers can get their time from.

So, you can either set all your machines to get their time from a single NTP server, or just use a PHP NTP client to pull the time from a central clock. Your call.  Check out an example here: http://xlo.co/blog/general/php-ntp-client

Is this what you are looking to do?

Comment: Thanks this is exactly the guidance I needed on this. I'll be looking into those sites. "Time" has always been a weakness of mine.

Answer (score 1):

You have to query a time server for that. These servers/communication use the Network Time Protocol to give a unified time across global network of computers.

Check http://www.ntp.org/

As far as querying these servers are concerned, it is a normal `fsockopen`

Maybe [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6959114/get-time-from-timeserver) will help you as well

Comment: Great, this is very useful. Looking into both of these answers.