# print current year in php without using date function

Tags: php, date

Is it possible to print current year in php with out using date function or any string functions.can any one help me to solve this issue

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't u want to use the built-in `date` function?

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to use a date function to show a ... date?

Comment: See this one [Get TIme from TimeServer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6959152/2279200) to get the date from a NIST server

Answer (score 2):

Of Course you can! It's just very stupid.
Here you go.

```
<?php
// First off, get the current timestamp. 
//This is every second, leading from 1970-01-01 till now.
$timeStamp = time();
// So there's a theoretically about 31536000 if we're having 365 days 
// and we're not on a leap year.

// However, there hasn't been 365 leap years since 1970, 
// so this shouldn't be a problem
$years = $timeStamp/31536000;
// Now we have the years that has gone by. We simply add them to 1970
$currentYear = $years + 1970;
// Remove the decimals
$year = floor($currentYear);
echo $year . "\n";
```

As you can see, this isn't a full proof long term solution. And I wouldn't recommend using this in any production code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `time()` instead.

```
echo 1970 + floor(time() / 60 / 60 / 24 / 365.25);
```