# Get correct time if it's changed on Window

Tags: javascript, php, cmd

as the title, how can I get correct date, time if it's changed by user
(with and without internet connection)
For example: real time is July 2nd 2015 and a user changed it into July 1st 2015,
so how can I get true value: July 2nd 2015???
(it's good if using php, javascript or cmd)
Help me please, thanks.
and sorry for my bad English.

**Edit:**

Thanks for your answer

about my project: I want to create a key, it has start and end date so that I must get current time to check if that key is out of date, if user changes time of Window to previous day, the key won't be out of date
(project will be installed and run on user pc)
thanks again.

Comment: wherefrom  do you expect to get the "true date" if you change the system's internal clock? There are Timeservers on the internet, but you can't use them without internet connection.

Comment: [get time from timeserver](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6959114/2152082)

Comment: you get "true" date by relying on the server's date/time, which you can display with PHP and not the user's system time, which the OP is referring to when he says that it can be changed to a day before.

Comment: i think, you should provide more information about your project if you want a good answer. where do you want to display the time? on a website? in an application? also, there's no possibility to get the real date and time if you don't have access to a (correctly configured) ntp server. @Stephan already provided a link with a solution for php.

Comment: Maybe checking the date of the last entry in the event log ("created after today"?). I have no experience in this, but you can start with `eventvwr /?`

Comment: Sorry, "last" entry could be after a changed date. (btw: just found: `Wevtutil qe /rd System /c:1 /f:text|find "Date:"` with `/c:xx` you get the last xx entries; maybe checking for a date after today within the last xx entries? (`|sort` might be helpful))