# windows batch file server time check

Tags: windows, batch-file, server

I was wondering if it is possible to create a windows batch file that checks the current PC time to a time sever on the web. Some servers time gets off sync and i wanted to get an alert when that happens.

Any ideas?

Comment: possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6959114/2152082)

Comment: @Stephan, it's not a duplicate. OP asks for windows batch, not php

Comment: Post the code you have tried

Comment: You can't do it with *pure* batch as there is no way to make a request to an NTP server.  You'll need to use something (an executable, PowerShell, etc.) that can make the request to the NTP server.  https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-Network-NTP-Time-with-07b216ca.  Is there any reason you want to use the severely limited batch language as opposed to PowerShell, which can do pretty much anything?